# Best practice to create a python class that manage an object list and how to include in UML diagram

Tags: python

I am trying to improve my object oriented programming skills. So I did this practice in python in which I try to create a cake object. However I have a doubt as to whether I am doing things correctly.

I need this class handle a list of ingredients.For this I created an empty list and a method that receives as a parameter an Ingredent object instance.

```
#Define a ingredient.
class Ingredient:
    #Constructor of ingredient
    def __init__(self, name,measure):
        #Name of ingredient
        self.name = name 
        #unit of measurement
        self.measure = measure

class IngredientQuantity(Ingredient):
    def __init__(self,name,measure,quantity):
        '''
        Here we are having access to methods and attributes from
        the parent class. Now we can set attribute values and access to
        methods.
        '''
        super().__init__(name,measure)
        #Define quantity of ingredient.
        self.quantity = quantity

#Define a list of ingredients.
class IngredentsList: 
    def __init__(self):
        #Empty list that will be populated with ingredients.
        self.listOfIngredients = []

#Add a new ingredient to list.
    def addIngredent(self,ingredient):
        print('adding ' + str(ingredient.quantity) + ' ' + ingredient.measure + ' of ' + ingredient.name + '...')
        self.listOfIngredients.append(ingredient)
```

Here is how I pass parameters...

```
ilist = IngredentsList()
ilist.addIngredent(IngredientQuantity('ingredient','piece',1))
```

I'm not sure this is the best way to do it. Then I would like to hear an opinion.

I also have doubts about how to treat this class in a UML diagram. This class is not inherited from any other. How could I relate it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any reason for creating a separate class for the quantity, as opposed to making it an attribute of the ingredient?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking about UML diagrams. You aren't required to use inheritance for an UML diagram

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The idea behind that abstraction is that I think it is different to specify an ingredient than the dose of it. I think this value is not essential to define an ingredient.

Answer (score 2):

An ingredient is just a string. Doesn't need a class.

A measurement, on the otherhand includes a unit and a quantity (e.g. 2 TBSP). So, create a class for that

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Measurement:
  unit: str
  quantity: float
```

Then you want to store a list of ingredients with measurements, so you can use a list of tuples

```
recipe = [
  ('Apples', Measurement(None, 1.0))
  ('Cinnamon', Measurement('tbsp', 2.0))
]
```

If you really wanted to create other classes, you could, but the relationships as far as UML goes is composition and aggregation, not inheritance.